# SIGSEGV while debugging in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I am running 32 Bit CodeBLocks(10.05) in my 64 Bit machine. It produces SIGSEGV all time. This is occurring in my Office PC. But in my home PC (32 bit and 10.05 codeblocks) no problem occur. I am attaching Call Stack window. Is there any problem with kernel32.dll ?

Please note that, for testing I just wrote a line of code. But still it produces SIGSEGV. I re-installed CodeBlocks 2-3 times. Is there any problem in my System ? I am almost crazy. :'(

[image]

As requested I am putting the simple code here:

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //READ("input.txt");
    //WRITE("output.txt");

    int i, j, k;
    int TC, tc;
    int x0, y0, x1, y1;

    cout << "hi";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the code directly here.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text windows.

Comment: you can zoom the image to read the text of Call Stack window. :)

Comment: i just tried with codeblocks 13.12. same as before.